# React js input not working after moving the code to a function

Tags: reactjs, function, input

The input was working with no problem, but I needed to move the input code into a function. Now I can only type in one word in the input value. Not sure what the solution would be to fix this issue. I'm also having a similar issue with my sorting function.

here is the link to my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-murdock-5uqfxs?file=/src/App.js

I created another function for the input, and still no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you define the `MyInput` component inside the `App` component. So in each re-render of `App` it will create a new `MyInput` component so it will lose focus and you need to re-focus the input.

Defining the `MyInput` component outside of `App` so that it is stable will fix the issues. You will have to pass the required values and handlers through props.

In general it is a bad pattern to define components inside other components, due to this kind of problems.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is dirty and painful to read.

You have unnecessarily used props almost everywhere. Your app is basically a to-do list for shopping items. The app Creates and Reads the data - the only two functionalities.

Also you have unnecessarily composed your basic app into multiple components within the main App component. Due to this, somehow your `inputValue` state doesn't exactly map to `username` inside MyInput.

Suggestion: Organize your state variables and reduce composition of components.

I am not trying to be rude, but your code is not organized. It is painful to read.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not a coder; I'm a User Experience Designer. I'm taking this class as an Elective in my MS HCI program. As you can see, this is very difficult for me.